# how to display 2 spring models in the same html table row using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to display the following row in an html table:

`"$num out of $totalCount"`

for example `num=5` and `totalCount=8`
I want to see in the table `5 out of 8`

here is my code:

```
...
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${num} out of ${totalCount}" />
        </tr>
...
```

I added `num` and `totalCount` as models in the controller.

I am getting the following error:

```
Could not parse as expression: "${num} out of ${totalCount}"
```

What is the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for string concatenation in Thymeleaf. See [String concatenation with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/01/11/string-concatenation-with-thymeleaf/) for an overview.

In this case, you can use something like this:

```
<td th:text="|${num} out of ${totalCount}|" />
```